# React Load hashed image from data while loading Image

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I m making a project with react and which i get the data from a JSON file. I load an image with URL

```
<img src={image} />
```

and I have a hashed image(blurred) in my data which i want to display while waiting to render the real image. Any what to do this?

JSON is like:

```
"hash": "UUKJMXvM{V@AHRQwvxZXSs9s;o0",
"image": "https://www.imageurl.com/",
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `react-progressive-image` which is a npm package used for progressive image loading. You can install it using:

```
npm i react-progressive-image
```

And then use it like:

```
<ProgressiveImage src={image} placeholder={hash}>
  {src => <img src={src} alt="an image" />}
</ProgressiveImage>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: i installed it with npm but i get error " Line 26:6:  'ProgressiveImage' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef"

Comment: You need to import it first before using like: `import ProgressiveImage from 'react-progressive-image'`